# How to call javascript function with php input value

Tags: php, javascript, input

I want to call a javascript function with parameter of php like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">formatCurrency(<?php echo $item['price']; ?>);</script>
```

unfortunatley, something goes wrong, html displays nothing, can someone sugest how should i do it?

Comment: See what is in HTML output ie. page source.

Comment: firebug shows no errors, html is simply clean, as if no output is given. And the formatCurrency() accepts both integers ant strings

Comment: You won't see any output as `<script type=` does not output anything. You need to print it somewhere.

Comment: @SilentCave like Voitcus states you must print it somewhere. At least you could put the result within an alert() function like this: **alert(formatCurrency(...))**

Comment: shorter syntax: <script>formatCurrency('<?=$item['price']?>');</script>

Answer (score 0):

It seems i forgot to add document.write(), and thanks for the shortening, looks nice. so

```
<script>document.write(formatCurrency('<?=$item['price']?>'));</script>
```